# 'device not ready' while using File.Copy() in C#

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I am trying to move databases from one SQL server to another.I am doing this through a Console written in C#. The methodology is a follows. I first detach the database, move the data and log files to the new location and then attach the files from there.
However after I detach the file, I am not able to copy the data and log files. The error that I get is :'device is not ready'.
I am using network paths for both the source and destination. I'm using the File.Copy() to move the files and I have permissions to create files in the respective folders

Comment: Can you test your copy method with a simple .TXT file? This might help narrow down the issue.

Comment: Can you please post some code specific to how you're attempting to copy the file?

Comment: Try running the Console application at Command prompt with elevated privileges and see if that resolves the issue.

Answer (score 3):

At a hunch, 'device is not ready' is not an C# exception generated by the File Copy command.  The possible exceptions are;

```
UnauthorizedAccessException, ArgumentException, ArgumentNullException, 
PathTooLongException, DirectoryNotFoundException, FileNotFoundException, 
IOException, NotSupportedException
```

So this 'error' could possibly be something which generated internally, as per the other comments, more information is needed.  In order to debug this problem I suggest the following

- Place a breakpoint in your code where 'device is not ready' text string is present in your code
- Check both paths in your code are valid paths
- Is your program is built to handle UNC paths or file paths?
- Possibly an exception is being silently caught, but you'll need to debug to find this out
- If your trying to move databases, have you stopped the Windows Service instance associated with the database?  Type services.msc from the run command, then scroll to SQL Server (*your SQL instance name*) then stop the service from there.  That would unlock the database file.

Good luck.