# Why is this email attachment failing on my asp.net server but not on local host?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

This code works perfectly on localhost/IIS express.  I receive the email with the attached pdf.  However, when I copy it to my server, IIS7, it fails.  Any ideas why?

```
   var db = new DirectCellarsModel();
            var status = false;
            MailAddress from = new MailAddress(EMAIL_SENDER);
            MailAddress to = new MailAddress(recipient);
            MailMessage message = new MailMessage(from, to);
            message.Subject = subject;
            message.Body = messageBody;

            if (pdf)
            {
                Attachment data = new Attachment(@"C:\develop\PDF\myfree.pdf", MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet);
                message.Attachments.Add(data);
            }

            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(SMTP_CLIENT);
```

This is the error message:

```
The device is not ready.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.IO.IOException: The device is not ready.


Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below. 

Stack Trace: 


IOException: The device is not ready.

   System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath) +1093
   System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost) +886
   System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share) +127
   System.Net.Mail.AttachmentBase.SetContentFromFile(String fileName, String mediaType) +104
```

Comment: Can you post the error message?

Comment: Sorry, meant to and just forgot.   " Device not ready" when trying to load the pdf file.

Comment: Okay... problem solved.  I recompiled everything on my local development box and re-deployed it to the server.  It has started working now, after 5-6 attempts... don't know why, but hey, its working....

Answer (score 0):

The error `Device Not Ready` typically indicates that the location given does not exist.  Usually it means that the drive itself does not exist, but in this case I cannot image that the server doesn't have a C drive (but it may not, the server can be booted from another device).  Check to ensure that the drive and the folder on the drive actually exists.

Check this answer as well for tips on debugging and other possible issues:

['device not ready' while using File.Copy() in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3804355/device-not-ready-while-using-file-copy-in-c-sharp)

If the location does exist, check that the user has permission to read it.  The anonymous user is identified by `IUser`.

Comment: What about the path to the file? Hardcoding the full path is never a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Even if the location "C:\develop\PDF\" exists on the server, the account under which your IIS_USER account (or another) may not have full permissions to access that location.

You may want to consider setting up a subfolder off the root of your website with the relevant permissions for the IIS account to easily access.